# Do I have to connect an iPhone to my Mac in order to create a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have enrolled to Apple Developer Program to release my first app. My app's bundle ID is the same at developer.apple.com, at appstoreconnect.apple.com and in my XCode project. However, XCode still gives the error in "Signing & Capabilities" tab:

> **Failed to create provisioning profile.**
>
> There are no devices registered
>   in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device
>   to have Xcode register it.

And another error:

> **No profiles for ‘com.xxx.yyy’ were found**
>
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS
>   App Development provisioning profiles matching ‘com.xxx.yyy’.

First error message made me think that a physical connection to an iPhone is required to create a provisioning profile.

I have never connected a physical device to my Mac before. I made my tests by iOS simulator. I was planning to do my physical device testing via Testflight.

Do I have to physically (via a USB cable) connect an iPhone to my Mac in order to create a provisioning profile? If not, what might be wrong?

Is it required to have provisioning profile in XCode to be able to use Testflight or publish an app to App Store?

Comment: I would follow as it says, and if you able to plug your device into your Mac, you should try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have to physically (via a USB cable) connect an iPhone to my Mac in order to create a provisioning profile?

Yes, if you want to use automatic signing. An automatic provisioning profile unites a computer and a device and an app; it says that this computer is allowed to build this app onto this device. Until Xcode sees the device, it can’t create the profile.

The alternative is to switch to manual signing. It’s more work but now you can generate the profiles yourself.

Comment: Is it required to have provisioning profile in XCode to be able to use Testflight or publish an app to App Store? Or is it only required to build the app for a local device (iPhone)?

Comment: You need a development provisioning profile to archive and a distribution provisioning profile to export from the archive to TestFlight.

Comment: Technically you can register a device UUID in the developer portal and create the provisioning profile that way, but it is much, much easier just to plug the phone in and have Xcode do it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

You do NOT need a physical iOS device (iPhone or similar) to upload an app to App Store! Whether for real or TestFlight.

I realize this qn is old now, but I'm writing this for people like me, who stumble in here fighting the same problem...

What you need to upload apps on App Store:

1. A MacOS machine (not too old)
2. A paid Apple Developer Account
3. An app signing certificate from the above account
4. A provisioning profile, with or without a physical device

When trying to create a new provisioning profile in your Apple Developer Account, the first option is:

#### iOS App Development

*Create a provisioning profile to install development apps on test devices.*

See:

[image]

If you chose this option, you need a physical device! In fact, the way I understand it, you are supposed to register the UDIDs of ALL the phones and tablets that you want to test your app on...

If, like me, you don't have an iOS device, you can instead chose the last option in the list:

#### Developer ID

*Create a Developer ID provisioning profile to use Apple services with your Developer ID signed applications.*

See:

[image]

This one only requires an Apple Developer ID!

At the end of your create-provisioning-profile process, you have to download your profile and open it in Finder to install it (in XCode or whatever you're using). In your project, you have to switch from "automatic signing" to "manual signing". In XCode, this is done here:

[image]

If, like me, you had already downloaded your app signing certificate and installed it in your `KeyChain` app, you may run into this error when trying to apply your provisioning profile:

"Provisioning profile 'your profile name' doesn't include signing certificate 'your certificate name'".

The way I solved this error was:

In KeyChain:

1. Exporting my Apple Developer certificate to a .p12 file.
2. Deleting my Apple Developer certificates.
3. Re-importing the exported certificate file to keychain.

In XCode:

1. Close and re-start XCode
2. In the "Signing & Capabilities" tab in the project, de-select the newly downloaded profile and then select it again.

Now, it works!  From there, you should be able to follow any tutorial for uploading an app to App Store.

Comment: Fine, now please delete your comment on _my_ answer.

Comment: Right!  Done.

Comment: In case someone else has the same issue, Developer ID still gave me the error that it was for Mac only. I had to choose "App Store" instead, then it worked.