# How to create provisioning profile without iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a problem. Xcode give me this two errors

```
Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
```

```
No profiles for 'com.companyname.appname' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.companyname.appname'.
```

I create app for iOS and now I want to add this app to App Store.

I created developer account and paid 100 $.

Then created Certificates 'iOS Development' and installed  on my Mac.

Then I created Identifiers where IDENTIFIER is like Bundle Identifier.

And I have this two errors... How to fix it? And when I want to create the profile I need to create Devices but I don't have iPhone... It is possible to do this without iPhone?

Comment: https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/229496268-iOS-How-to-Create-a-Provisioning-Profile

Comment: @Niki still same errors

Comment: See this answer on duplicate qn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434155/14335655

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have not registed any devices to test this on , you have to attach your device annd get the UUID of the device and add it as a testing device on the provisional profile .

First goto the apple developers account and the certificate/identifier and profile tab. In the left tab bar you would notice a tab called `Devices` . Click to it and you will be navigated to a page where they allow you to add devices . In the devices tab , click the "+" icon and add a new device to your device list .
[image: Click On the Devices Tab]

To retrive the UUID connect your device to your laptop/mac and open the ITunes , in it you would notice a small tab icon indicating the "phone" . Open it and you would notice the device information in the image displayed below. Click on the Serial Number Key and until it changes to UUID and right click on it and copy it . Come back to the developer profile add the UUID and add the device . Now go back follow the normal procedure and make the profiles and add them to your app . Hope this was help ful
[image: Click on the Serial Number]

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Filip clearly said he does not have an iPhone! So when you say "your device", what do you mean? The iPhone that he doesn't have?

Comment: Please see this answer on duplicate qn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434155/14335655

Comment: This does not apply, since he does not have an iPhone.